# Single UITextField input multiple items without keyboard closing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, keyboard, uitextfield

I'd like to achieve the following behaviour of a single `UITextField` and the keyboard:

1. when the view has loaded `UITextField` becomes first responder and the keyboard opens (so far so good):

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
      [self.editField becomeFirstResponder];
      self.editField.delegate = self;
   }
   ```
2. Now user inputs some text and presses the return key. That text is added to the data source in the following method:

   ```
   - (IBAction)didEndOnExit:(id)sender {
     //add self.editField.text to data source
   }
   ```
3. Now after the return key is pressed and the above `UITextField`'s method gets called and executed I would like the `UITextField` to clear, the cursor to be placed and be visible at the beginning of the text field and the keyboard not to hide so that new item could be entered in the textfield and added to the data source.

This is how I return to the previous view in the app (using a button):

```
- (IBAction)backButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{}];
}
```

I tried playing with `UITextFieldDelegate`'s methods and `UITextField`'s `becomeFirstResponder` and resign `FirstResponder`, but am unable to achieve the above described behaviour. I've seen posts here on Stack Overflow about using consecutive `UITextField`'s to enter data, but not to use the same `UITextField` time and again.

Answer (score 1):

You should override the below mentioned method and do whatever you want and showing the keyboard too.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

Have a try :)

Comment: This is not very specific.

Answer (score 1):

While dismissing view controller all other code executions freezes when (view controller is being dismissed).
Use some delay (performselectorafterdelay). or

completionhandler of dismissingviewcontroller for executing your code when viewcontroller is being dismissing and

Also execute code on main Thread which includes UI changes or updates

Answer (score 0):

after saved your data.. you have to make the uitextfield to be nil... like self.editField.text = nil. then you can call [self.editfield becomesfirstresponder].. after you will add more items to array or else anything everytime the field should be nil after you added..

Answer (score 0):

*From the Doc*

> **Return Value:** YES if the text field should implement its default
>   behavior for the return button; otherwise, NO.

For EX - Use the Delegate of `UITextField` :

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    //add self.editField.text to data source
    textField.text = @"";

        return NO; // This will do your need
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Keyboard still closes. That is because after the above method gets called the textfield automatically stops being first responder.

Comment: It will only work if I remove all UITextField action methods like didEndEditing and so on. They close the keyboard. Then I won't even need to return NO.

Answer (score 0):

Because I used UITextField's action method `- (IBAction)didEndOnExit:(id)sender` the keyboard always got closed. Apparently that method makes the UITextField resign from being first responder. Instead of adding data to data source in that method, it can be added in the delegates's method `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField` and so the keyboard won't close.